# Add custom form data into ORDER tab (WooCommerce)!

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I have created one custom form (Wordpress Woo-commerce) for purchasing products.

I need to insert data into ORDER tab OR After Orders I would like to create one more tab called Subscription Orders same like Orders, but inside this post type data is only for subscription orders.

Can you please guide and help me, How I can achieve this. I have also put screenshots so you can get better idea.

Thank you in advance.
[image: Front End Form]

[image: Need to create new custom menu after orders or we can directly put into orders]

Answer (score -1):

try to override template of woocomerce via themes
and use the hooks. 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: can you please elaborate more. I am very new to WooCommerce.@markantonay